# Run command automatically after login?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, login

Another quick question. I have installed f.lux on Ubuntu 12.04, however the program refuses to work unless I run a command

```
xflux -l [longitude] -g [latitute] -k [temperature]
```

So I've created an alias with my settings so that I simply have to type the command `startflux` in a terminal at login. I want to automate this process so that my alias (or the full command above) will run after login, how would I go about doing so?

I've read bits and pieces about editing the `rc.local` file, however trying this didn't seem to work? What exactly is the `rc.local` file and `etc/init.d/` and how are they used?

Thanks!

Comment: login to what? Gnome? or I guess it's Unity on Ubuntu 12.04 - but are you talking graphical?

Comment: Another quick question!!!

Answer (score 2):

`gnome-session-properties` can be used to configure startup applications.

Also, if you want an application to run at system boot, you can add a rule like the following to your crontab (edit crontab with `crontab -e`):

```
@reboot /run/this/program/at/boot >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are connecting via ssh, you can edit your `.bashrc` file located in your `home` directory, and add in it the command you would like to use.

It will then be executed at login.

I'm not sure if it works if you are using GNOME (or KDE etc). I cannot test it right now.

Comment: `~/.bashrc` is not read by login shells (which is what you run when connecting through `ssh`). While on Debian derivatives, including Ubuntu, `~/.profile` (which _is_ read) calls `~/.bashrc` by default, you cannot assume this to be the case always.