# Bash cannot see PATH update

Tags: bash, shell, debian, login, path

I am running Debian on a VM.  I login to the GUI and go to Applications > Accessories > Terminal.

`# echo shell: /bin/bash`

I modified `ENV_SUPATH`, `ENV_PATH` inside of `/etc/login.defs`.  I restarted the shell.  In superuser mode `echo $PATH` shows my update.  In normal mode `echo $PATH` does not show my update.  I added and modified `~/.bash_profile`.  I still can't see my change and I'm starting to chase my tail.

`/etc/login.defs` contents:

```
ENV_SUPATH      PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/home/brian/.linuxbrew/bin
ENV_PATH        PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/home/brian/.linuxbrew/bin
```

`~/.bash_profile`:

`PATH=/home/brian/.linuxbrew/bin:$PATH`

How can I troubleshoot and resolve this?

Comment: I may be wrong but I seem to recall that ENV_PATH in /etc/login.defs is now obsolete and ignored.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain how you are logging in to this machine. Are you running a login or a non-login shell?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/122430/25985

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: also adjust `/etc/profile` (and `/etc/sudoers` carefully)

Long answer: The PATH variable is defined in multiple places.

According to [login.defs(5)](http://linux.die.net/man/5/login.defs), only `su` uses it.

The `sudo` has it's own secure PATH definition in `/etc/sudoers` (variable `secure_path=...`)

Most Unix shell will read `/etc/profile` and `~/.profile`. In Debian, this file is used to define login shell's PATH. Bash also reads `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`.

...and probably more (run `grep '\<PATH\>' /etc/ -R`)