# Running program on startup (Fedora 22/ 2015)

Tags: linux, startup, command

I tried really hard to avoid posting a new question for something so basic and already answered in a hundred places, but after spending two hours on this and trying every solution out there I'm thinking they're either outdated or don't apply to the current version of Fedora.

What I tried (among other things):

- `gnome-session-properties` (doesn't exist anymore)
- `gnome-tweak-tool` (can only add existing applications to startup, ie: can't add custom commands)
- my working `.sh` script in `~/.config/autostart` (chmodded executable)
- `.desktop` file in `~/.config/autostart`
- script in `rc.local` (this appears to be ignored now)
- script in `/etc/init.d`(chmodded executable with `sudo`)

The above all fail to run my script on start up.

The script I'm trying to run:

```
#!/bin/sh
xcompmgr
```

Or even simply this command:

```
xcompmgr
```

My exact setup:

```
Fedora 22
Kernel 4.0.4
Gnome shell 3.16.2
Awesome WM 3.5.6
```

What is the simplest, up-to-date way of running a command or script on start up on my setup?

Comment: If you want to do it on user log on: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122424/execute-a-command-on-user-logon

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem. It seems that the key to really enable it is `Version=1.0` that I can bet you missed.
You can also disable autostart item or delay it's start by adding:

```
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-Delay=2
```

You can also use great example with:

```
ln -s /usr/share/applications/pidgin.desktop ~/.config/autostart/pidgin.desktop
```

Full example, that should work:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=xcompmgr
GenericName=xcompmgr
Comment=xcompmgr
Exec=/path/to/xcompmgr
Terminal=true
Type=Application
X-Desktop-File-Install-Version=0.22
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me on Fedora 22 (GNOME Shell 3.16.2 / Kernel 4.0.4-303.fc22.x86_64): ~/.config/autostart/conky.desktop

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=conky
GenericName=Conky
GenericName[hu]=Conky
Comment=Rendszeradatok
Comment[hu]=Rendszeradatok
Exec=/usr/bin/conky
Terminal=false
Type=Application
```