# xbindkeys map Left + Right mouse button to Middle mouse click

Tags: lxde, openbox, lubuntu, xbindkeys

I have managed to install xbindkeys on my lubuntu 16.04 box, which I think is the correct tool for me to use to map a simultaneous left and right mouse button click to emulate a middle mouse click.

I originally thought I should do this using the openbox configuration file (I am using lxde with openbox) but couldn't find a way of doing it.

Can I do this with xbindkeys? If so how? I can't get my head around how the system works as I am totally unfamiliar with it.

Answer (score 3):

No, xbindkeys can't detect simultaneous button presses. But you don't need that to emulate a middle click on left+right click: it's a built-in feature.

You can turn it on with the [`xinput`](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/man/man1/xinput.1.xhtml) program. See [Make mouse movements scroll when the middle button is held down](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101867/make-mouse-movements-scroll-when-the-middle-button-is-held-down/102011#102011) for a tutorial. In a nutshell:

- Run `xinput list` to list available input devices. Locate the name of your mouse device; I'll use `My Mouse Device` in my answer.
- Run `xinput list-props 'My Mouse Device'` to list the available properties. One of them should be `Evdev Middle Button Emulation`.
- Run `xinput set-prop 'My Mouse Device' 'Evdev Middle Button Emulation' 1`

Once you have the command right, add it to your autostart list, i.e. create a `.desktop` file in `~/.config/autostart`. See [Running program on startup (Fedora 22/ 2015)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209898/running-program-on-startup-fedora-22-2015/228376#228376) for an example.