# Run Script After Unlocking GDM

Tags: x11, gdm, autostart

Hi I already tried all solution from [execute-a-command-on-user-logon](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122424/execute-a-command-on-user-logon), and used PostLogin option of GDM.... The problem is all of these option are only works when system boots up but it's not what I Ask.

I want an script execute everytime user unlocking his/her account after awakening from suspension.

I Already used systemd and udev but they are not the solution because

1. My script have depend on X so I have to be sure that X is already started
2. The script should run as the user that login not root.

I use GDM 3.20 on Arch Linux

---

I dont realy care if the script runs before login (for example script run for all avalible user)

Comment: My script need to run after unlocking only, but if there is an solution that run everytime in all situation you mentioned it's good and will solve my problem completely too.

Comment: Indeed it is, Thanks your solution works for me.... Anyway how can I mark my question as duplicate