# How to start a dialog at startup after login in?

Tags: startup, init.d, rc, xinit

I want to display a dialog at startup after the user log in?

**How would you suggest to do automatically launch a dialog at startup?**

Example of dialogue:

```
zenity --question
```

Comment: What desktop environment are you using?

Answer (score 1):

As [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/122430/146295) states, it might depend on what display manager you are running, but you can try to add the `zenity` command to `~/.xprofile`.

I don't really suggest you to add it to `~/.profile` as it will try to execute it when you login in a shell (i.e. in terminal) and it will probably fail if it has not a display defined (for instance if it is a remote ssh connection).