# How to hide cursor pointer when not in use?

Tags: linux, cursor

I have used unclutter but it only remove the cursor  while the command is running in the terminal. It does not provide the permanent solution. I do not want to run the command every time.

Presently  what I am doing is that I am calling a script form desktop file

from /etc/xdg/autostart/single_start.desktop

the desktop file **single_start.desktop
**

```
enter #!/usr/bin/env xdg-open

[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false'
Exec=bash /etc/xdg/autostart/single.sh
Name=Chromiumrelaunch
Comment=comment here
Icon=icon path here
```

the file **single.sh **is

```
#!/bin/bash

lxterminal -e unclutter -idle 1 &
sleep 10
xdotool windowminimize $(xdotool getactivewindow)
```

So the unclutter terminal window still comes so I am using xdotool to minimize the window. What I want is that unclutter works permanently in the background.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute a command on user logon](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122424/execute-a-command-on-user-logon)

Comment: After adding the command in startup script, the unclutter terminal remains open . It does not run in the background.

Comment: What is the command you are running? What have you done exactly?

Comment: There is desktop file which runs on start up and under that i am running a shell script.  The shell script is located at /etc/xdg/autostart/shell.sh

Comment: What are the contents of that file? Please add all this information to your question.

Comment: i have edited the question

Comment: `single.sh` is launching a terminal window to run the command, which is unnecessary. You just need to run the command directly. i.e. just `unclutter -idle 1`. For simplicity, just put it in the desktop file's `Exec` section.

Comment: but how to make unclutter -idle 1 executable in desktop file exec?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. `unclutter` should already be executable. What happens when you try what I suggested?

Answer (score 1):

Just add `unclutter` to your desktop environment’s startup applications. It won’t open a terminal and stay running in background.

If you invoke `unclutter` from within a script don’t forget adding `&`

```
unclutter &
```

I recommend giving [xbanish](https://github.com/jcs/xbanish) a try which implements the `-keystroke` option broken in `unclutter`

Refer to [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/681214/how-to-enable-keystroke-option-of-unclutter-in-unity) for more infos about compiling `xbanish`

Edit: You do not need to run unclutter in terminal to make it work.

Comment: I did that. I have put & at the end.